# is it possible to get latitude and longitude form mapKit and use it in google map?

Tags: swift, xcode

nothing to say more than the title 
**Code:**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
import GoogleMaps

class onlyMapVC: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var theMap: GMSMapView!
    //    @IBOutlet weak var upperView: UIView!

 var currentLat = 0.0
var currentLong = 0.0



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    theMap.delegate = self


    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


        currentLat = (locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!
        currentLong = (locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!


        let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: currentLat, longitude: currentLong)
                  marker.map = theMap

        self.theMap.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: coordinates, zoom: 6.0, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)


    }
```

but the result wasn't correct it shows me somewhere so far from my current location any help ?

i'm using Xcode 10 swift 4

Comment: `currentLat` and `currentLong` variables don't exist in the code above. Of course you can use a coordinate in another map SDK, coordinates are universal

Comment: if its possible why they shows my another location what is the best way to get my current location using google map ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423615-locationmanager) you should receive location updates via the delegate method `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)`.

> **startUpdatingLocation()**
>
> This method returns immediately. Calling this method causes the location manager to obtain an initial location fix (which may take several seconds) and notify your delegate by calling its locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:) method. After that, the receiver generates update events primarily when the value in the distanceFilter property is exceeded. Updates may be delivered in other situations though. For example, the receiver may send another notification if the hardware gathers a more accurate location reading.

So you should call `startUpdatingLocation` and wait for the delegate method to be called when the GPS location has been received.

So try something like this:

```
class onlyMapVC: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var theMap: GMSMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        theMap.delegate = self

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, 
           didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let currentLocation = locations.first?.coordinate
        marker.map = theMap

        self.theMap.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: currentLocation, zoom: 6.0, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)

    }
}
```

Make sure your UIViewController has the protocol `CLLocationManagerDelegate`

Answer (score 1):

You're setting both currentLat and currentLong to the longitude:

```
currentLat = (locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!
currentLong = (locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!
```

Should be:

```
currentLat = (locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!
currentLong = (locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!
```

Comment: Good spot, completely missed that myself

Comment: great notice i fixed it but still shows me so far location not mine :(

Comment: Maybe the locationmanager hasn't had time to update the location when you access it in viewDidLoad? As @Scriptable wrote, you should use the delegate method to get the updated location.

Comment: Are you trying this on a device or in the simulator, btw?

Comment: on my own iPhone X